# Why does Firefox suggest I have mistyped my domain?

Tags: firefox

If I type my own domain into the Firefox address bar it will suggest that I may have mistyped it and offer to "protect me" by redirecting to a large commercial website which is the same as my own domain but with one vowel removed.

If I check the Google Safe Browsing diagnostic page there is "nothing suspicious" about my domain.  I do not get the big red "malware" page, only a suggestion that I have mistyped something.

What criteria is Firefox using to make this recommendation?

Comment: Have you checked your computer for malware? This is very common for malware to do. Try 2 different anti-virus scanners for the best results. At work, we use [AVG Free](http://free.avg.com/us-en/homepage) and [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is the "typo correction" feature of Adblock Plus.  Reading the [source code](https://hg.adblockplus.org/adblockplus) shows that it is loading some kind of database from [urlfixer.org](http://urlfixer.org/).  Their database seems to be built from user contributions, although comments in a blog post suggest it was seeded by "popularity".  So this has nothing to do with my own URL and everything to do with it being close (by [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) to a popular online commerce site.